# ¿Cómo usar sólo n valores vinculados a imágenes dentro de una lista para copiarlas encima de otra imagen base en Python con el módulo Pillow?

Tags: python, lista, bucle-for, pillow

```
from PIL import Image
imagen_base=Image.open(imagen_base)
a = Image.open(a)
b = Image.open(b)
c = Image.open(c)
d = Image.open(d)
e = Image.open(e)
f = Image.open(f)
    
lista=[a,b,c,d,e,f]
```

1. En primer lugar, tendría una imagen base:

   imagen_base=Image.open(imagen_base)
2. En segundo lugar, tendría una lista de imágenes:

   a = Image.open(a)
   b = Image.open(b)
   c = Image.open(c)
   d = Image.open(d)
   e = Image.open(e)
   f = Image.open(f)

   lista=[a,b,c,d,e,f]
3. El objetivo sería obtener tres nuevas imágenes; colocar encima de la imagen base las combinaciones ab, cd y ef gracias a la función paste dentro del módulo.

Comment: Lo que deberías de hacer es: primero hacer una máscara de capa de la imagen que quieres poner por encima, después solo usa la función de "image.composite" y pasa como parametros tus 2 imágenes y la mascara de capa de la imagen. Recuerda que las imágenes son matrices  de bytes y pudes cambiar el modo a HSV  o GrayScale según convenga mas para manejar mejor los colores. Si subes las al menos dos imágenes que planeas combinar puedo ayudarte con mas información del proceso. Para invertir unamascara puedes utilizar una funcion bitwise.

Comment: Gracias, y para que en la lista se usen valores de dos en dos, ¿cómo lo podríamos hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres usar solo los valores de dos en dos te recomiendo usar un bucle for con pasos de 2. Por ejempló si tienes 10 elementos:

```
lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for i in range(0, len(lista),2):
    print(f'elemento {i} con elemento {i+1}')
```

output:

```
elemento 0 con elemento 1
elemento 2 con elemento 3
elemento 4 con elemento 5
elemento 6 con elemento 7
elemento 8 con elemento 9
```

En tu caso:

```
for i in range(0, len(lista),2):
    imagen1 = lista[i]
    imagen2 = lista[i+1]
```

Dentro de la misma iteración juntas las imágenes y produces la nueva imagen.